# Pixelformer pencil and brush don't work

Tags: pixelformer

I've used Pixelformer before to do detailed editing of images, but, after restoring my laptop (and installing a fresh copy of Pixelformer) I can't get it to work.

Images load fine and I can select and crop and that sort of stuff.  But when I try to draw with pencil or brush nothing happens -- the pixels don't change.

Anyone have any ideas why this might be?  I've tried just about every key/button combo I can think of, and have even looked at the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind -- it started working after I switched the selection tool out of "round".